# Can Aqua Data Studio automatically connect to a database on startup?

Tags: database, aquafold

Is it possible to make Aqua Data Studio connect to a certain database and open a query editior window for it on startup?

I have tried to find documented parameters to pass to datastudio.exe or settings to set on the individual databases (ie "Connect on startup"), but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to Server Properties -> Scripts tab and in case of RDBMS that lets you change the database using the use database, enter your database as in attached screenshot.[image]

Now open up a new Query Window and the database of your choice is available as default. Let me know if this works for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't quite accomplish what I'm looking for. I'd like Data Studio to automatically connect to a certain server and open a query for a certain database as soon as it is started. This solution will automatically select a certain database when I connect to a server, but I still have to connect to the server manually. Is there a way to do that also automatically?

Comment: Take a look at File->Options -> General -> Workspace and enable Restore windows and tabs. If you exited the application, and had File > Options > General > Workspace > [Restore Windows and Tabs] enabled, relaunching ADStudio would resurrect all the tabs that had been open when the application closed. It will automatically connect to your open Server and then if you had a SQL Query already, it would restore that as well and you can quickly execute.

Comment: https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation15/page/242/Saving-Workspace

Comment: Brilliant! That does it! Thanks a lot, had lost faith there was a way :)